# Best .net framework version to work with Windows xp,7,8 without installing or updating it separately

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-xp

I am going deploy a Windows Form application developed in C# using Visual Studio 2012. I do not want the user to download or update .net framework version. So what is the best .net framework version that most of the windows versions come with pre-installed and enabled ?
(Preferably Windows xp,7,8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most commonly installed .Net version is .Net 2, However WinXP does not have a default .Net framework installed

From Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework

```
.NET Framework 1.1: Windows Server 2003
.NET Framework 2.0: Windows Server 2003 R2
.NET Framework 3.0: Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008
.NET Framework 3.5: Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2
.NET Framework 4.0: n/a
.NET Framework 4.5: Windows 8, Windows Server 2012
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it pre-insalled and enabled on all the versions ?

Comment: I feel that 3.5 is the most supportive according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)

Comment: This Wikipedia article is misleading. The .NET Framework is an **optional component** in many of those versions of Windows. Yes, it shipped on the installation media, but it is *not* guaranteed to be installed. I have a box running Server 2008 R2 that definitely does not have .NET 3.5 installed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assume that *any* version of the .NET Framework is installed. [Windows is not a .NET Framework delivery channel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/04/10149346.aspx).

It is absolutely imperative that you have a plan to install the version of the framework on the computer if it is not already installed. Generally, this is handled by an installer program, but you can also use ClickOnce deployment if you prefer.

The general strategy is just to choose the highest version of the framework that supports the operating systems you need to support and go with that one. Install it when it is not already installed.

Comment: That is so absulitely untrue in modern windows - which is, given that you point to an article from beginning 2011. Powershell - required standard install on all current windows - requires .NET framework to be installed.

Comment: why can't I assume that any version of .net framework is pre-installed. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)

Comment: Server 2008 R2 is still "modern" in my book, and there is absolutely no guarantee that the .NET Framework is installed. Yes, if you've installed PowerShell, .NET will be there. But PowerShell is not "required". It, too, is optional. @tom

Comment: @CodyGray 2008 R2 is not current though. It is 2 generations behind. Mandatory powershell started exactly the generation after that. So, current AND last generation windows have .NET mandatory installed.

Comment: So I think .net framowork 3.5 is a good answer if I explicitly do not want to install it ?

Comment: @user What gives you that idea? TomTom is saying that because PS 3.0 is mandatory on Windows 8, you are guaranteed to have .NET 4.0 installed. Of course, that's *only* Windows 8. You'll still have to install .NET 4.0 on older versions of Windows. And before Windows 8, there is absolutely no guarantee that any version of the .NET Framework is installed.

Comment: I am thinking about windows 7,8,8.1. So thought that idea according to the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history)